# Javascript Dynamic Data Duplicating- Old Data Not Getting Refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a JavaScript & Jquery Learner. I have a popup in which it shows the date at the top. Please see the image below:

[image].

When I click on a date and generate the popup the previously generated remains and the new `date` comes to the top. It's getting duplicated or the previous `date` is not getting refreshed, below are the codes which I am using for the dynamic popup. Thanks in Advance.

```
 function GetEmployeeDayAttendance_ForSheet_popup(events) {
    $('#dayAtt_Sheet_Popup').modal("show");
    $('#dayAtt_Sheet_Popup').modal({
                show:false,
                keyboard: true,
                backdrop: "static",
                show:false,
            });
        $("#dayAtt_Sheet_Popup").on("shown.bs.modal", function(event, ui) {

        $('#dayAttendance_sheet').html( '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" id="tblDayAtt_sheet"><\/table>' );
            var oTable = $('#tblDayAtt_sheet').dataTable( {
                "bPaginate": false,
                "iDisplayLength":15,
                "sScrollY":200,
                "sScrollX":"100%",
                "aaData": [],
                //"aaSorting": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
                "asStripeClasses": [ 'strip1', 'strip1'],
                "aoColumns": [                                          
                    { "sTitle": "Swipe Time" },
                    { "sTitle": "Emp ID","sClass": "text-center"},
                    { "sTitle": "In / Out","sClass": "text-center" },
                    { "sTitle": "Map View","sClass": "text-center"},
                    { "sTitle": "Latitude","bVisible": false},
                    { "sTitle": "Longitude","bVisible": false}
                ]
            } );     

            $('#tblDayAtt_sheet_filter').parent().prepend('<div id="dateChange_sheet" class="singleLine-text">'+$("#fromDate").val()+'  Day Attendance Details</div>');    
            $('#tblDayAtt_sheet_filter').hide();
            var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width:639px)")
            if (mql.matches){ // if media query matches
             $("#dayAttendance_sheet").mCustomScrollbar({
                        axis:"x",
                        horizontalScroll:true,
                        alwaysShowScrollbar: 0,
                        advanced:{
                            autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true ,  updateOnContentResize: true, updateOnBrowserResize: true 
                            },
                        theme:"dark",
                    });
            }


             // =========== END =================
                    GetEmployeeDayAttendance_ForSheet(events);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in line

```
 $('#tblDayAtt_sheet_filter').parent().prepend('<div id="dateChange_sheet" class="singleLine-text">'+$("#fromDate").val()+'  Day Attendance Details</div>');
```

In above line of code new date is prepended and old date is not flushed. That s why old data is not getting refreshed.